# Add extra rows in a data frame according to a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe such as

```
SP_names    Gp1 Gp2 Gp3 Gp4
Sp1 0   0   1   1
Sp2 0   1   1   1
Sp3 1   1   2   3
Sp4 1   3   6   1
Sp5 0   2   0   2
```

and a list such as :

```
list<-c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3","Sp4","Sp5","Sp6","Sp7")
```

and the idea is that for each element in the list that are not present in the SP_names, I want to add a row (so fo `Sp6` and `Sp7 filled by 0`) and get:

```
SP_names    Gp1 Gp2 Gp3 Gp4
Sp1 0   0   1   1
Sp2 0   1   1   1
Sp3 1   1   2   3
Sp4 1   3   6   1
Sp5 0   2   0   2
Sp6 0   0   0   0
Sp7 0   0   0   0
```

Have you an idea with R?

Comment: BTW, you wrote you have a list, but with `c()` you had created a vector, which is not a list.

Answer (score 1):

An idea via base R, by building a custom function to (in essence) handle the row names,

```
f1 <- function(df, list) {
    rownames(df) <- df$SP_names
    df[setdiff(list, df$SP_names),] <- 0
    df$SP_names <- rownames(df)
    rownames(df) <- NULL
    return(df)
}


f1(d2, list)
#  SP_names Gp1 Gp2 Gp3 Gp4
#1      Sp1   0   0   1   1
#2      Sp2   0   1   1   1
#3      Sp3   1   1   2   3
#4      Sp4   1   3   6   1
#5      Sp5   0   2   0   2
#6      Sp6   0   0   0   0
#7      Sp7   0   0   0   0
```

**NOTE:** If your `SP_names` column is a factor then the above function will throw a (harmless) warning. My recommendation is to convert your `SP_names` to character (If not already)

Answer (score 0):

We get the elements that are not in the 'SP_names' column with `setdiff`, bind the original dataset with those and change the `NA` to 0

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- setdiff(list, df1$SP_names)
bind_rows(df1, tibble(SP_names = v1)) %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)
#   SP_names Gp1 Gp2 Gp3 Gp4
#1      Sp1   0   0   1   1
#2      Sp2   0   1   1   1
#3      Sp3   1   1   2   3
#4      Sp4   1   3   6   1
#5      Sp5   0   2   0   2
#6      Sp6   0   0   0   0
#7      Sp7   0   0   0   0
```

---

Or use `add_row`

```
library(tibble)
add_row(df1, SP_names = v1)
```

---

Or using `complete`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  complete(SP_names = list, fill = list(Gp1 = 0, Gp2 = 0, Gp3 = 0, Gp4 = 0))
# A tibble: 7 x 5
#  SP_names   Gp1   Gp2   Gp3   Gp4
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Sp1          0     0     1     1
#2 Sp2          0     1     1     1
#3 Sp3          1     1     2     3
#4 Sp4          1     3     6     1
#5 Sp5          0     2     0     2
#6 Sp6          0     0     0     0
#7 Sp7          0     0     0     0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <- merge(df1, data.frame(SP_names = list), all = TRUE)
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SP_names = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp5"
), Gp1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Gp2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), 
Gp3 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L), Gp4 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```